# Split a string into an Array On white space but what if I have a string with one word

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file, one sentence per line. I would like to split the sentences on white space. To do that I did the following:

```
 String[] splitStr = line4.split("\\s+");
```

My problem is that some lines include only one word. So this line got lost with the above regex. For example:

```
  I like to play football 
  Nice
```

The line with "Nice" word will not be added to the "splitStr" array.So how can make the above regex consider the lines that include only one word. Thanks,

Comment: Try "\\s?" instead of +

Comment: It did not work, thanks though

Comment: [Your code works alright](http://ideone.com/Gq8MrB), have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is correct. I think there is something wrong in your code. Try out this one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

        try {

            String line = br.readLine();
            List<String> splitStr = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (line != null) {
                splitStr.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s+")));
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            System.out.println(splitStr);

        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

If you try with a file having below content:

```
test1 test2 test3
test4
test5 test6
test7
```

Output would be:
[test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7]

If you try with a file having below content:

```
I like to play football 
Nice
```

Output would be:
[I, like, to, play, football, Nice]

Answer (score 1):

After some testing in which I prove that my answers that I put before were wrong, now I have the solution:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(//Here the path of your file));

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while (s.hasNext())
{
    list.add(s.nextLine());
}

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
   String[] line  = list.get(i).split("\\s+");

   System.out.println("I'm in the line " + i);

   for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++)
   {
        System.out.println(line[j]);
    }
}

s.close();
```

As you can see, I made two loops, the second one it's not necesary but I put it to check that the split function was doing its work fine for each line of the file.

Note: I had to add `throws IOException` to my main class like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  //Here the code
}
```

I expect it will helps to you!

Comment: I edited my question now. Before it doesn't work, now it works perfectly (I check it in my Eclipse). I expect it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually mistaken about how `split` behaves. Your code will work.

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely [the original] string.

Source: [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for String

Answer (score 0):

> The line with "Nice" word will not be added to the "splitStr" array.

That's correct, you are splitting a *different* string into either the same or a different array. If into the same array, the current contents will be *replaced*.
Consider:

```
String[] splitStr;
String line4 = "I like to play football";
String line5 = "Nice";

splitStr = line4.split("\\s+");
// splitStr contains [ "I", "like", "to", "play", "football" ]
splitStr = line5.split("\\s+");
// splitStr NOW contains [ "Nice" ]
```

You have *replaced* the 5-element array with a 1-element array — split does not *Add to* an existing array, it always produces a new one.

You will have to either split the whole file at once, or add each set of split results to some kind of master list.

Comment: One way of keeping a master list is to do `someList.addAll(...)` as @Ani shows in the sample program.